# How does Python solve 6/-132?

Tags: python, integer-division

In Python, `6/-132` gets an answer of `-1`, but should that be a `0`?

What's the rules behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python floors the result, which means that 1/2 floors to zero, but 1/-2 floors to -1. This is different than C, which 'truncates toward 0'. AFAIK, most languages follow C. Python uses different rules to keep division 'in sync' with modulo. This article does a good job of explaining.

http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html